# image painting in 2.7 image editor

Tags: texturing, image, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

i was following a tutorial about texture painting, and i can't seem to find the Image paint in the Image list ( UV/Image Editor ) in blender 2.7, did they remove the option or put it in another place ?

Comment: add some screenshots to your question. where did you expect to find it? where did you look for it...

Comment: are you looking for the "paint mode" switch? in the UV/image editor header there's a selection list, by default it shows "view" but you can set it to "paint".